# Set cookie on checkbox click (with jquery)

Tags: jquery, cookies, setcookie

I have a login form for which I would like to store the username (input field: username) in a cookie via Jquery the moment I click a checkbox ('remmber me'). Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

This guide shows how to use the Cookie plugin for jQuery: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/

Then you can use something like this in your javascript files:

```
$(function() {
  $(".rememberme").change(function() {
     if ($(this).is(":checked"))
       $.cookie("loggin", $("#username").val(), {expires: 7});
  }
});
```

Comment: Ok, looking good. How do I echo the value in the username field?

Comment: How do you mean? The value of the username field is retrieved by `$("$username").val()`.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon [Henridv's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6083794/906658), I ended up doing this:

```
$("#remember_me").change(function() {
    $.cookie("remember_me",
             $(this).is(":checked"),
             {expires: 7, path:'/'}
    );
});
```

Note that my solution also sets the cookie to false, if the checkbox is deselected. In other words, this keeps the cookie current.